# Login from my page on to one.com control panel with the same username and password

Tags: javascript, php, json

Im woundering if there is any way that i can create a login page on my website for my customers and then redirect them to the control panel on one.com without having to whrite their username and password again?

This is the action page on one.com https://www.one.com/admin/login.do

Comment: Possibly yes, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please provide code, otherwise we can not debug for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your code so that we can help you out :)

Comment: I uploaded the code, now i have 1 issue left. If i type the wrong password when i try to login, im being redirected to one.com login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it worked with this code :)

```
<html data-version="v5.46.2-0-g2d63fa5/login.one.com" lang="sv">
<body class="small-width" style="">
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script async="" src="//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KQ4H"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
<script src="//login-static.cdn-one.com/bundle-589.84ef5fa5db.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha256-n1FzNRmLWUtQ9eoTKpQ8+7FA1zcAiFTvJuVkCSfFb1Q="></script>

<noscript>
<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KQ4H" height=0 width=0 style=display:none;visibility:hidden></iframe></noscript>

<div class="notification" data-bind="notification: notification" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="errormsg" data-bind="errormsg: errormsg" style="display: none; top: -2px;"></div>
<div class="layout application">
<div class="layout top">
<div class="one-bar--logo"><a class="one-bar--logo--link" href="https://www.one.com/"></a></div></div>
<div class="layout center container">
<div class="layout top one-bar"
<a class="one-bar--applications--item--link icon apps apps-cpanel" href="/cp/">
<span class="apps-title">Kontrollpanel</span>
<a class="one-bar--applications--item--link icon apps apps-webmail" href="/mail">
<span class="apps-title">Webbmail</span></a></div>

<div class="layout app center"><div class="layout right"><div class="login-dialog dialog">
<form class="login autofill" data-bind="submit: userLogin" action="https://www.one.com/admin/login.do" method="POST" novalidate="">
<h1 class="welcomeText">Logga in till kontrollpanelen</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="loginDomain" value="true"/> 
<input type="email" name="displayUsername" class="username" data-bind="value: loginForm.displayUsername,valueUpdate: ['input','afterkeydown']" placeholder="E-post" required=""/><input type="hidden" name="username" data-bind="value: loginForm.username"/>
```

```
<div class="clearfix"></div> <input type="hidden" class="loginTarget" name="loginTarget" data-bind="value: loginForm.loginTarget"/> <div class="loginErrors" style="display: block;"><p data-bind="visible: !loginForm.isLoginValid()" style="">E-postadressen eller lösenordet du skrivit in är inkorrekt. Prova igen.</p><p data-bind="visible: enterUsernameAndPassword" style="display: none;">Skriv in din e-postadress och ditt lösenord.</p><p data-bind="visible: invalidUsername()" style="display: none;">Användarnamnet du angav är ogiltigt.</p><p data-bind="visible: invalidPassword()" style="display: none;">Lösenordet du angav är ogiltigt.</p><p class="boxedLoginError" data-bind="visible: loginForm.isLoginObsolete() === true" style="display: none;">Logga in med din e-postadress. Det går inte längre att logga in med ditt domännamn.<br /><br /> <a href="https://www.one.com/admin/adminuser-send-create-email.do">Skapa en ny inloggning</a><br /><br /> <a target="_blank" href="https://www.one.com/sv/support/faq/om-du-inte-har-skapat-en-ny-inloggning-annu">Om du inte har skapat en ny inloggning ännu</a></p></div><div class="buttons"><button type="submit" class="oneButton">Logga in<i class="icon-arrow-cicle"></i></button></div><p class="forgot_password"><a href="https://www.one.com/admin/forgotpassword.do">Har du glömt ditt lösenord?</a></p></form></div></div><div class="layout center"><div class="login-separator"><div class="login-previewpane"><div class="preview-images preview-images--controlpanel"></div><div class="preview-images-2x preview-images-2x--controlpanel"></div></div></div></div></div>



<script type="text/javascript" id="">(function(a,c,e,f,d,b){a.hj=a.hj||function(){(a.hj.q=a.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};a._hjSettings={hjid:898148,hjsv:6};d=c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];b=c.createElement("script");b.async=1;b.src=e+a._hjSettings.hjid+f+a._hjSettings.hjsv;d.appendChild(b)})(window,document,"https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-",".js?sv\x3d");</script><iframe name="_hjRemoteVarsFrame" title="_hjRemoteVarsFrame" id="_hjRemoteVarsFrame" style="display: none !important; width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; opacity: 0 !important; pointer-events: none !important;" src="https://vars.hotjar.com/rcj-99d43ead6bdf30da8ed5ffcb4f17100c.html"></iframe><div id="ads"></div></div></div></body></html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, If you find the login URL for one.com (easily found with the inspection of the login button usually), then you can redirect a post request to that url with username/password as post data.

However, most sites will implement some form of CSRF protection (stopping requests from other websites to their website for protection). But you can test this easily when you find the login url